# A tauri app where user input a text and sends it as notification

Tags: tauri

I am learning tauri, I just want the enter a text from HTml and send notification with that text. I read the tauri docs and GitHub page but I could not figure it out.

https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/notification/
https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not supported according to this github discussion: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/6017